# QML context menu size adjusted to its content

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm confused with Qt Quick size policy, width, implicit widths, bounding etc. I have `Menu` which popup when click on round button. Problem is that menu is too big. Look at attached screenshot. Items should have alignment set to right:

[image]

I'm able to do that by setting `Layout.fillWidth: true` on icon `Label`:

[image]

but still, menu is to big, I have fixed size `300` but I would like to adjust its size to content. Also, space between items is to big even when spacing, padding and margins are set to 0. I'm using material dark style. Here is code:

```
Menu {
    id: roundButtonMenu
    modal: true
    spacing: 0
    padding: 0
    margins: 0

    Action { text: qsTr("File"); icon.name: FAIcons.faFile}
    Action { text: qsTr("Folder"); icon.name: FAIcons.faFolderOpen}
    Action { text: qsTr("Link"); icon.name: FAIcons.faLink}

    delegate: MenuItem {
        id: menuDelegate
        spacing: 0
        padding: 0
        contentItem: RowLayout {
            spacing: 0
            Label {
                id: mIcon
                text: menuDelegate.icon.name
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                font.family: FALoader.icons
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.color: "red"
                }
            }
            Label {
                id: mLabel
                Layout.fillWidth: false
                text: menuDelegate.text
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.color: "red"
                }

            }
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "transparent"

        }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 300
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#21be2b"
        radius: 2
    }
}

CPRoundButton {
    id: btnAdd
    iconfa: FAIcons.faPlus
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    onClicked: {
        roundButtonMenu.x = 10
        roundButtonMenu.y = 10
        roundButtonMenu.open()
    }
}
```

Comment: i would try to add to your backgrounds and RowLayout: ```width: childrenRect.width height: childrenRect.height``` and remove the Layout.Fill properties.

Comment: Didn't help. Adding it to Menu's rectangle results that menu is not visible at all and adding also into RowLayout result with `QML RowLayout: Binding loop detected for property "width"`